# As of .NET Core 3.0 is "MidpointRounding" a misnomer?

Tags: c#, rounding

.NET contains an enum to specify [midpoint rounding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-6.0) modes:

- **AwayFromZero** *(Available since .NET Core 1.0)*
- **ToEven** *(Available since .NET Core 1.0)*
- **ToNegativeInfinity** *(Available since .NET Core 3.0)*
- **ToPositiveInfinity** *(Available since .NET Core 3.0)*
- **ToZero** *(Available since .NET Core 3.0)*

It seems that some of these enum values are used to determine how to round midpoint values, whilst others apply even when not rounding by the midpoint.

Consider the following code:

```cs
for (decimal value = 1.0m; value <= 3.0m; value += 0.1m)
{
    MidpointRounding[] roundings = Enum.GetValues<MidpointRounding>();

    foreach (MidpointRounding rounding in roundings)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{value} {rounding} = {Math.Round(value, rounding)}");
    }
}
```

This creates a lot of output, which would unnecessarily bloat this question, so I've highlighted a few notable outputs:

> **value** *rounding mode* = ***rounded value***
>
> **1.1** *ToPositiveInfinity* = ***2***
>
> **1.9** *ToNegativeInfinity* = ***1***

Is seems then that `MidpointRounding` is a misnomer, since it contains rounding modes that do not operate on the midpoint.

Would this be a correct observation?

Comment: It does seem that `MidpointRounding` was correctly named until .NET Core 3.0, when they extended it with new enum values but kept the same name, so that now it is indeed a misnomer. I think they should have created a newly named enum type instead.

Comment: That seems to be how it's documented to work (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-6.0#directed-rounding).  That's truly a badly named feature.  It breaks the principal of minimizing programmer surprise that @EricLippert has talked about over the years.

Comment: Renaming an enum breaks compilation of old code. Also breaks ability of .NET Core 3 to run DLLs built against .NET Core 2, unless implementing non-trivial compatibility support in the runtime. These compatibility features gonna need to be support for years, inevitably causing issues in the long run. Apparently, someone at MS decided a misleading enum name is the lesser evil.

Comment: Fractional values can be considered as midpoints between integers, even though most values are not literally in the 'middle'. I never noticed up to now that it can be misleading.

Comment: Instead of extending the MidpointRounding enum, they could have created a new enum and overloaded the `Math.Round` method to take both enums. Then in the next version they could deprecate the MidpointRounding overloads.